# Is it possible to use USGS .shd files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, cartography

Has anyone successfully used QGIS with US Geological Survey shd files to map geology - specifically to display colors and geological symbols (dip/strike etc) stored in a USGS supplied shd file.
Looking for a non arc solution.

Comment: Are these files publicly available (for testing?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer to this is no, QGIS cannot read .shd files; these files are ARC/INFO specific files for holding shadeset set information (colour and patterns).